# #SQL optimization order model

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem with Optimization ORDER on my school project.
SO we must create package with Order  - 1 package  - is max 3 order ( now is easy ) 
but we must  optimize orders so that the pack as many of the same indexes as possible
The algorithm will work for 1000 orders, 50 indexes  per order .

Someone have idea to resolve this problem ? 
I use MSSQL

Example 
pack 1 - order  'd' 'c' 'a'
pack 2 - order 'h' 'g' 'e'
pack 3 - order 'b' 'f'

```
 ORDER  indeks  QTY
a   1xx 5
a   2XX 5
a   3XX 5
a   4XX 5
a   5XX 5
b   2XX 5
b   3XX 5
b   4XX 5
c   1xx 5
c   2XX 5
c   6XX 5
c   5XX 5
c   7XX 5
d   1xx 5
d   2XX 5
d   3XX 5
d   7XX 5
d   8X  5
d   9X  5
d   10XX    5
e   4XX 5
e   5XX 5
e   6XX 5
f   1xx 5
f   2XX 5
g   5XX 5
g   6XX 5
g   7XX 5
g   10XX    5
h   6XX 5
h   7XX 5
h   9X  5
h   1xx 5
```

Comment: You add `non-cluster index` in your table include filed `Package` and `OrderID`

Comment: Which dmbs are you using?

Comment: Hi                  I use MS-SQL